# A JNI error has occured when running my program as a JAR from IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cmd, java-native-interface, executable-jar

My code compiles and runs without issue in IntelliJ. However when I try building the program as a JAR and running in cmd, I get the following error.

> ```
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/log4j/Layout
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
>         ... 7 more
> ```

I believe I am creating the JAR correctly. Here are the libs I am bundling in. [image]

I create the JAR by adding an empty JAR to the artifacts tab, then adding the META-INF, libs, and code manually.
[image]
As you can see, lib is contained inside which does hav log4j and apache commons.

Note this issue only pops up when the JARs are created from IntelliJ. If I create a JAR via eclipse the JAR works just fine, but that isn't viable.